# Google Maps API - disabled on domain

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When page loads i get the message as javascript alert: 
`Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. See the Terms of Service for more information: http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html.`

Everything working fine till today. Google webmasters tool didnt told me anything.

My question is wherer can i find more informations why exacly this page has been banned/blocked. (In terms there are lots of possible reasons)

What to do to unblock this? Who or where to send the request?

Comment: I just got this same message today and I haven't yet made a _single request_ to their API. All I've done is include their Javascript file in a script tag. I don't see _anything_ in the TOS docs that suggest to me what could be wrong.

Comment: I just got this same error as well.  Everything working fine until this morning. All we're doing is displaying a small map of each of our client addresses

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Have been using the API for months, and then this afternoon I tried to load up the application and got this alert box. :(

Comment: Can you guys provide the URLs to the sites that are showing the message?  Thanks.

Comment: Site is located at http://www.fish-team.com/en/contact (i hope it is not a rules violation to provide link like this :P)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My web application had this same error occur, and we fixed it by updating our link to the Google Maps API file.

Previously we were using a downloaded version of the Maps API file located at http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE.

When we instead used the direct link, this particular error went away.

**Edit:** Even if you're directly linking to Google's js file, make sure your application isn't using an older locally cached version.

Not working version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="local_google_maps_api.js">
```

Working version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
```

Google likely started invalidating Google API v3 calls using older address versions. The Javascript code files mainly differ in the API IP address call

Comment: I am using online version all the time. Maybe google made some verification system "upgrade" and no one was informed about it?

Comment: Michael - a quick look at your link (fish-team) shows you are also using a locally cached copy of the js (/js/cache/6......js) instead of linking directly to the http://mapos.googleapis.com/... version.  Switch to using the hosted javascript and you shold be all set.

Comment: Good point jlivni. I'll update my answer to mention locally cached versions of the js.

Comment: Thanks jlivni, i thik i missed that(so many others google map scripts).

Answer (score 1):

For everyone getting this error / alert, you must:

1.) Ensure that you are linking to the online API, as noted by Steve Feng. Replace your code for accessing the Google API file with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
```

2.) Make sure you clear your page's cache - even if you were already accessing the file with the code above(like I was). This may be done quickly if you're working on a Windows platform by pressing [ctrl] + [F5], or by pressing [cmd] + [R] on a Mac(or ['apple'] + [R]). On linux a simple [F5] should force refresh. If this button combination didn't work(or doesn't apply to you), look at [this website](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/) for more information on clearing your cache.

After you've cleared your cache and made sure your code accesses the API file from the URL posted above, you should not get that message anymore(as far as I have experienced).

AFAIK, this message appears regardless of you actually breaking Google's Terms and Conditions or not. Furthermore, I have found this message may appear when using a Google API that isn't Google Maps. One example of a complaint [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/maps/56hL3dsrxuY%5B1-25%5D) (at bottom).

I have no straight evidence to believe this, but I think this message became Google's default(-ish) error message when you did something to upset one of their APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly have this warning in a web app on iPhone Safari only, after everything working fine for months. iPhone Chrome browser works and desktop mac safari and chrome works. Can't see where the terms are being broken

Strange! Clearing my cache and cookies on iPhone has cleared the problem. Map works fine now. Must be some change in the api which is triggering the problem for users who have recently visited

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the Google maps script **from you local machine causes this issue**.

Just reference it back to the remote version and add the `?sensor=false` to the end and you should be good to go.