# Geocode OVER QUERY LIMIT workaround

Tags: jquery, google-maps, geocoding

I'm trying to geocode more than 1,000 addresses and store the values in an XML file. The problem is I'm getting an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error after the tenth address.
I've seen other posts suggesting waiting X seconds between each geocode, but that doesn't seem to work for me. Here's a piece of my code:

```
<div id="locations"></div>
$(xml).find('marker').each(function (i) 
{
    var storeName = $(this).attr('name');
    var address = $(this).attr('address');

    setTimeout(function(){
        g.geocode(address, function(data) 
        {
            if(data != null) 
            {
                olat = data.latitude;
                olng = data.longitude;

                var marker = "<marker name='" + storeName + "' lat='" + olat + "' lng='" + olng + "' />";

                $('#locations').append(marker);
            } 
            else 
            {               
                  //Unable to geocode
                  alert('ERROR! Unable to geocode address');                  
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Geocode 20 addresses without receiving an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419219/how-do-i-geocode-20-addresses-without-receiving-an-over-query-limit-response)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First a note about [Google's Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12)**

It's easy to not think about stuff like this, but it does matter sometimes. Unless you want to join [this group from earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863709/google-maps-api-disabled-on-domain) which for some reason had their service disabled, make sure that you are showing a map to the user as you geocode these addresses. The TOS also prohibit bulk geocoding and storing the results for anything other than performance caching.

Not accusing! Just bringing to attention.

---

The programmer answer:

`setTimeout`'s callback and `geocode` are both asynchronous functions. Right now with your code, while the response is still coming back from the API, you're starting your 1-second timer which also runs asynchronously while your loop continues to iterate immediately with no delay. After one second, the no-op is called once then discarded. This happens each time the loop is run.

So you're shooting off a thousand API requests at once. Then about 1 second later (give or take a few milliseconds), 1,000 no-ops will run.

Your calls to `g.geocode` need to be inside the callback function of `setTimeout`, and then the end of the callback function will need to set another timeout with itself inside it, until you are done. No more no-op.

If you want to more correctly "work around" the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` errors and other TOS restrictions (like geocoding *en masse*), you'll want to consider a commercial service that doesn't have such limits, something like [LiveAddress](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) (disclosure: I work at SmartyStreets).

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for the reminder. I'm trying to build a store locator, so there shouldn't have any trouble with Google's Terms of Service. I tried following your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. I updated the code above with these changes.

Comment: Geocoding more than a thousand addresses at once? Sounds kind of bulk to me, but it's not up to me to decide, I guess; hopefully you will find more fortune than some others! Anyway, your code isn't working  because `each` is still iterating without delay. Double-check the part where `setTimeout`'s callback has to start the next iteration; don't let `each` run away from you.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the quick response. Yes, I intend to save the coordinates in an xml so then I can be able to show stores near the user's location. It's not just to be able to place a marker in a specific position in the map, but to show the nearest stores. Regarding the code, you lost me there. Placing the each inside the setTimeout would shoot 1,000 API requests at once, and once it's done, the no-op will run... Right?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to clarify: `each` is not waiting because `setTimeout` does its stuff to the side all the meanwhile. There's two good ways to fix this: You'll either need to control when the next iteration is called (right now it just keeps going), perhaps by setting a new timeout inside a `setTimeout` callback. Or, as I've seen elsewhere, you can set the number of ms to be `1000 * i` where `i` is the index of the current iteration. Then you don't have to wait to call iterations as your timeouts keep getting extended.

Comment: Hi Matt. Yes, sorry. I haven't been able to try it until now, and that seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: any chance you could show me the code snippet for settimeout that has worked for you???